# cfcollection/org.apache.poi errors on cf2016 with some .ppsx files

Tags: java, coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-2016

has anyone ever had any trouble with cfcollection on cf2016 and indexing certain .ppsx files? some update or something has caused certain .ppsx files to now throw one of 3 errors when indexing;

**org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(Ljava/io/File;Z)V**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(Ljava/io/File;Z)V at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.getTopLevelNames(POIFSContainerDetector.java:403) at

**org/apache/poi/hwmf/usermodel/HwmfPicture**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hwmf.usermodel.HwmfPicture at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:252) at

**org/apache/poi/hemf/extractor/HemfExtractor**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hemf/extractor/HemfExtractor at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.EMFParser.parse(EMFParser.java:77) at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280) at

if i test on the same cf/java version, i don't get those errors

Comment: I don't know how coldfusion is packaged and if there is something like OSGi involved, but the HEMF/HWMF classes were introduced in POI 4.0.0 IIRC and the POIFSFileSystem was also unified around that time. So my guess is, you are using a newer TIKA version and have either old or duplicated POI jars in your classpath.

Comment: (Update) `if i test on the same cf/java version, i don't get those errors` Test how? What's your full CF/java version numbers?